# Every Ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of a Dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}$ can be generated by $2$ elements

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

An exercise in Neukirchs book about algebraic number theory is to show, that every ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of a Dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}$ can be generated by $2$ elements [or is principal].

Neukirch suggests to use that $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ is a PIR, which I already showed in the exercise before. [and I want a solution which use these fact]

*What I got so far:*
Take an arbitrary ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathcal{O}$, so $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ is a PIR. This means that for $a \in \mathcal{O}$ $a \neq 0$, $(a)/ \mathfrak{a}$ is a principal ideal of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$, so there has to be an $b \in \mathcal{O}$ s.t. $(a) + \mathfrak{a} = (b)$

But actually now I am stuck. I do not even know, if this leads to a solution.
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: $(a)/{\frak a}=(b)$ seems to be equating an ideal of ${\cal O}/{\frak a}$ with an ideal of $\cal O$. Perhaps you mean $(a)+{\frak a}=(b)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $(a) / \mathfrak{a} = (b)$ does not make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{a}=(0)$ or $(1)$ then $\mathfrak{a}$ is principal, so assume that $\mathfrak{a}\neq (0)$ or $(1)$.

Then there is some $a\in\mathfrak{a}$ which is non-zero and not a unit. By what you have already shown, the quotient $\mathcal{O}/a\mathcal{O}$ is a principal ideal ring, so there is some $b\in \mathcal{O}$ such that the image of $b$ in $\mathcal{O}/a\mathcal{O}$ generates the image of $\mathfrak{a}$ in this ring.

Hence if $x\in\mathfrak{a}$ then $x=ya+zb$ for some $y,z\in\mathcal{O}$, which shows that $a$ and $b$ generate $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: Could you explain, why the image of $b$ in $\mathcal{O} / a \mathcal{O}$ generates the whole image of $\mathfrak{a}$ and not just a subset.

Comment: Because $\mathcal{O}/a\mathcal{O}$ is a principal ideal ring.